# Abstract Algebra Proof by Induction

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

**Prove that if $\sigma$ is the m-cycle $(a_{1} a_{2} ... a_{m})$ then for all $i \in \{1,2,...,m\}$, $\sigma^{i}(a_{k})=a_{k+i}$, where $k+i$ is replaced by it's least positive residue mod m.**

Immediately I thought to use induction but I just want to be certain that I've done it correctly (I'm very new to writing actual proofs).

First, note that for $i=1$ we have 
$$
\sigma^{1}(a_{k})=a_{k+1}
$$
proceeding with the induction, by hypothesis we have that
$$
\sigma^{i}(a_{k})=a_{k+i}
$$
holds and then we have
$$
\sigma(\sigma^{i}(a_{k}))=\sigma^{i+1}(a_{k})=\sigma(a_{k+i})=a_{k+i+1}
$$
and since our hypothesis holds for $i+1$, we can conclude that our hypothesis holds for all $i \in \{1,...,m\}$.

Answer (score 0):

As it is proof-verification, I interact through an answer.

Your proof lacks of final analysis of the boundary case when $k+i=m$.

Comment: So would it go something like: Let k+i=m and then assume $\sigma^{i}(a_{k})=a_{k+i}=a_{m}$ and then $\sigma(\sigma^{i}(a_{k}))=\sigma^{i+1}(a_{k})=\sigma(a_{k+i})=\sigma(a_{m})=a_{m+1}=a_{1}$?

Comment: Absolutely ! to be quite complete (a) you explicit the case study  [(i) $1\leq k+i<m$ (ii) $k+i=m$] and you conclude with the _same_ conclusion (here "k+i+1" is replaced ...). This is, here, called "reasoning by case disjunction".